# Ansible update file using line numbers

Tags: templates, yaml, ansible, line-numbers

How can I get Ansible to update all the lines after line 9 with my file changes, leaving the previous lines alone?

I am using Ansible to keep the files across my servers uniform. I have put together a handy file which I can deploy to a server to get my settings and configurations setup quickly. This file is used by multiple users and each user has their own unique information in the file.

Currently, I distribute my copy of the file to everyone. Then I use lineinfile tasks to replace my info with the user specific information. This means however, that I have to maintain the user specific information not only in the file but also in my playbook and has been causing some headaches.

Additionally, if there was a way to not override the user specific information then I can create a bash function allowing me to specify which users I want to update.

Here is my current playbook:

```
---
- hosts: dmz
  vars: 
      curUser: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
      allUsers:
        - { name: johnDoe, gecos: "John D, XXXX S Sad Ln" }
        - { name: janeFrank, gecos: "Jane F, XXXX W Happy Dr" }
  tasks:
## =============== Updates the user's /foo/bar/user/FILE with the /foo/bar/FILE
    - name: distribute_File
      sudo: yes
      template: src=/home/{{ curUser }}/FILE dest=/home/{{ item.name }}/FILE owner={{ item.name }} backup=yes
      with_items: allUsers
      ignore_errors: true

## ===================================== Update user specific information
    - name: updateName
      sudo: yes
      lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ item.name }}/FILE regexp="^username=" line="username={{ item.name }}"
      with_items: allUsers

    - name: updateGecos
      sudo: yes
      lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ item.name }}/FILE regexp="^usergecos=" line="usergecos=\"{{ item.gecos }}\""
      with_items: allUsers
```

Comment: Can you have markers (comments) in this file? Then it should be possible with `lineinfile` to write out your base template as well. I have not tried it yet, but there is a `blockinfile` module on Galaxy: https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/1475 - which would speed up your play if you write multiple lines.

Comment: Could you give us more information on what you are actually trying to achieve? What is that file and what is an example of what you want it to become? There may be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @udondan Yes I can put comments into either file. Though the blockinfile looks like it searches for a string and replaces it. I am actually looking for the opposite functionality. I want to find a string and preserve it while changing everything else.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides It is an account setup file that holds lots of scripts and information for creating an account quickly and accurately. Each user has a variety of unique account information that needs to be preserved during the update. The rest of the file is generic and works for all users. Does that help explain the situation?

Comment: So the first 9 lines contain user-specific configuration, whereas the rest of the lines always contain the same information? It would be preferable to separate this file in two - the first 9 lines would be one user-specific configuration file, the rest would be a file common for all. It's like separating a program from its configuration.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Thank you for the idea, but I've already explored that avenue. In order to implement that change we would have to do some major reworking of the scripts and the supporting files.

In my experimenting and research there's the Replace function, though I can't figure out how (or if) I can use another file as the source. Are you familiar with that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is: 
Register the information first via fancy shell and register commands.

Then I used template to copy the new file.

Lastly I used the registered information in lineinfile commands to replace the specific lines with the registered information.

It's not as elegant or simple as I was hoping, but it's working. Thanks to Antonis and udondan for the ideas, they helped me think through the problem as a whole.